# I don't understand this sentence: I realized I had far from enough for the fare only after I reached the ticket box

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I don't understand this sentence, especially the highlighted part

> I realized I **had far from enough** for the fare only after I reached the ticket box

If you guys understand it please explain to me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To have far from enough for the fare means that the person didn't have enough money to buy a ticket.

"Fare" is a payment for travel, and the rest of the sentence means that it is not a case of missing for example 1 cent to the whole price, but more like not even having 50% of the required money. And that is a long way from having enough.